# How to transform an array with alphanumeric key/parent_key to a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

**How to transform an array below to a nested array?**

Please, see expected result code.

By the way, in my real application I'm using SHA-1 hash values as keys & parent keys.

So, all keys are unique.

Thanks.

```
$arr = array(
  array(
      'key' => 'apple',
      'parent_key' => 'root',
      'name' => '1'
       ),
  array(
        'key' => 'banana',
        'parent_key' => 'root',
        'name' => '2'
       ),
  array(
      'key' => 'sun',
      'parent_key' => 'apple',
      'name' => '1.1'
  ),
  array(
      'key' => 'moon',
      'parent_key' => 'root',
      'name' => '3'
  ),
  array(
      'key' => 'mars',
      'parent_key' => 'sun',
      'name' => '1.1.1'
      )
);
```

Expected result:

```
$arr = array(
  array(
       'key' => 'apple',
       'parent_key' => 'root',
       'children' => array(
                          'key' => 'sun',
                          'parent_key' => 'apple',
                          'name' => '1.1',
                          'children' => array(
                                             'key' => 'mars',
                                             'parent_key' => 'sun',
                                             'name' => '1.1.1'      
                                             )
                          )
  ),
  array(
       'key' => 'banana',
       'parent_key' => 'root',
       'name' => '2'
  ),
  array(
       'key' => 'moon',
       'parent_key' => 'root',
       'name' => '3'      
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($initial_array as $subarray){
    if($subarray['parent_key'] == 'root'){
        $final_array[$subarray['key']] = $subarray;
    }else{
        $final_array[$subarray['parent_key']]['children'][$subarray['key']] = $subarray;
    }
}
```

The only thing here is that, looking at your example, this code can only handle a depth of one. If you have a `'parent_key' => 'sun'`, for example, this will not work.

Comment: Grexis, the code you've posted gives me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']'

Comment: Fixed it. That last line is kinda complicated :D

Comment: Grexis, thanks. Is it possible to transform with any depth? I've edited my answer a bit.

Comment: It is possible. I would have to research it first. More than likely, it will require some use of [array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)